# Frame-by-frame animation with transparent images on canvas is laggy

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

How can I remove the stutter effect?

- Can the canvas be only cleared if the next frame is "ready"?

The demo only works when screen is scrolled (so I suggest looking at it in the small preview). Also, the lag problem seems not as bad in the preview here. But in Chrome e. g. the image occasionally just disappeares for a few ms/frames - leaving the canvas completely transparent.

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("prodPicAnimation");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 120;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `https://www.dr-adler.com/content/produkte/Sheabutter/renderAnimation/${index.toString().padStart(3, '0')}.png`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);

canvas.width=750;
canvas.height=750;

img.onload=function(){
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = 750;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
```

```html
  <canvas id="prodPicAnimation"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is lag related to the speed of `drawImage`/`clearRect`. I think this is a race condition with replacing the image `src`. Here's a solution without any scroll issues, where it preloads and precreates all `img` tags in an array. https://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/poOwmNb?editors=1010

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("prodPicAnimation");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 120;
const imageUrls = new Array(frameCount).fill(0).map((_, index) =>
  `https://www.dr-adler.com/content/produkte/Sheabutter/renderAnimation/${(index + 1).toString().padStart(3, '0')}.png`
);

console.log(imageUrls);

const preloadImage = async (src) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { resolve(img); }
    img.src = src;
  })
}

const preloadImages = () => Promise.all(imageUrls.map(url => preloadImage(url)));

canvas.width=750;
canvas.height=750;

const updateImage = img => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const init = async () => {
  const images = await preloadImages();
  document.getElementById('loading').remove();
  console.log('Ready', images[0]);
  updateImage(images[0]);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    const maxScrollTop = 750;
    const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
    const frameIndex = Math.min(
      frameCount - 1,
      Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
    );

    requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(images[frameIndex]))
  });
}
init();
```